# html+css : Avoid text under circled numbered List li, ol

Tags: html, css

Being fairly new to CSS trying to create a circled list with text. 
 I have a ordered numbered list having text on each li element. 
    I have added a CSS for adding a circled number to each text than the native number list ( 1. 2. )

My HTML code:

```
<ol>
    <li class="stepButtonsWV">Add all the panorama nodes.
        <br>
        <br>
    </li>
    <li class="stepButtonsWV">Add plans (optional).
        <br>
        <br>
    </li>
    <li class="stepButtonsWV">Place the nodes on the plan and create links between them.
        <br>
        <br>
    </li>
    <li class="stepButtonsWV">Preview your Panorama, modifiy the nodes altitude if necessary, test the
        navigation between the nodes and calculate your panorama for the Web and/or
        the mobiles.</li>
</ol>
```

CSS code:

```
ol {
    counter - reset: li;
}

li.stepButtonsWV {
    list - style - type: none;
    counter - increment: li; /* repas on incrÈmente le compteur ‡ chaque nouveau li */
    margin - bottom: 10px;
}



li.stepButtonsWV: before {
    content: counter(li);
    padding: 1.5px 6px 1.5px;

    background - color: rgb(63, 63, 63);
    border - style: outset;
    border - width: 2px;
    border - radius: 30px;
    border - color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    font: bold 10px;
    border - style: solid;
    text - align: center;
}
```

The problem is the output list is circled number List but all the text is coming under the numbers on each new line. 
 I dont want to hard code the new line as my application window is resizable and the text can drop off to new line.

I also tried to create a textarea,p html subelement on each li but it drops off to new line instead of continuing from the circled numbers.[image]

Attached is the output of what I get from the css and native list code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Working DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pxPh/)

One option is to wrap `li` text in `p` tag and add this CSS:

```
p{
    position: relative; 
    top: -35px;
    left: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
margin-left: -20px; text-indent: 20px; // or padding-left
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
  li.stepButtonsWV{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this:

```
li {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```